# Using Xor to encode and decode

Tags: java, jsp, encryption, xor

I am attempting to make a JSP that takes text from the text area and depending on whether you select encode or decode, will encode your text or decode the encoded text. The encode part works, but the decode option throws

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "".

Here is my code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Xorcoder</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <label>Key</label><input type="text" name="key" />
        <p>Encode<input type="radio" name="option" value="encode" /></p>
        <p>Decode<input type="radio" name="option" value="decode" /></p>
        <p><textarea name="txt" style="width:400px;height:200px" >
            <%String txt = "";
                int key;
                String option = "";

                if(request.getParameter("txt") != null) {
                    txt = request.getParameter("txt");
                }

                if(request.getParameter("key") != null) {
               key = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("key"));
                }
                else {
                    key = 0;
                }

                  if(request.getParameter("option") != null) {  
                option = request.getParameter("option");
                  }

                   char temp;

                   int[] array = new int[(txt.length())];

                      if(option.equals("encode")) {
                      for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                       temp = txt.charAt(i);
                       array[i] = temp^key;
                      }


                      for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
                        out.print(array[i] + " ");
                      }

                      else if(option.equals("decode")){
                      String[] array2 = txt.split(" ");
                      int temp2;

                      for(int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
                          temp2 = Integer.parseInt(array2[i]);
                          temp2 = temp2^key;
                          out.print((char)temp2);                              
                       }                                               
                   }

                      %></textarea></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Press" /></p>
        <p><input type="reset" value="Clear" /></p>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Obviously .... why is it throwing that exception, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem starts here:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
    out.print(array[i] + " ");
  }
```

This outputs the array with a space after each number.  Not between each number.

You then split that string like this:

```
  String[] array2 = txt.split(" ");
```

and (unsurprisingly) the last element of the array is going to be an empty string.

Solutions:

1. Don't output the final space in the first place.
2. Trim the string before splitting
3. Check that the strings are non-empty before calling `parseInt`.

(You don't need to check for `null`.  The spec for `split` guarantees that there will be no nulls in the array ...)

Comment: @Robert have you seen my answer? you have many blank spaces in your textarea because of the way how you wrote your **html** code

Comment: @Lysenko Andrii I just read your response. You are right about the html tags, which I am a little rusty on. I didn't implement that if statement in my last loop yet. Using trim solved the issue. But I will try what you suggested. Thank you for taking time to work on my issue, I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.NumberFormatException` tells you that `""` is not a number.  Problem is with you usage of `Integer.parseInt`. Before using `Integer.parseInt(...)` please check if the input of that element is not empty (and not null, check this condition only if the parameter can be null, otherwise not required). If it is empty, `Integer.parseInt` will throw that error.

Comment: In this context, testing for null is redundant.

Comment: I agree, but for safety measures and to spread more aware about usage of `Integer.parseInt` :)

Comment: Your are recommending an **unnecessary** safety measures.  That is bad.  You are implying that it is OK to add null tests (and empty strings) without understanding what causes the problem in the first place.  That is bad too.

Comment: I'm not implying to add condition without knowing the reason. I myself gave the reason for exception :). Edited answer accordingly, to suit future requirement :)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, all you need to do to solve your conundrum is to add an **if** statement into the last loop in your code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
   if (array2[i].isEmpty()) //checks whether the length of string is 0
      continue; //skips current iteration and moves further
   temp2 = Integer.parseInt(array2[i]);
   temp2 = temp2^key;
   out.print((char)temp2);                              
}
```

Also I'd like to tell that not having any space between such tags as **<%**, **%>** and other html tags makes your textarea somewhat cleaner. I mean, try to use

```
   <textarea name="txt" style="width:400px;height:200px" ><%
```

Instead of

```
   <textarea name="txt" style="width:400px;height:200px" >
      <%
```

so that you will not have any useless space characters in your textarea.

Good luck :)